# Prevent RegExpt from returning matched string that is not between parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match all the emails that are after the text *"Email: "*

However, when using `match`, the matches return the whole string: `Email: demo@example.com`.

Isn't there a way to just return the text matched by the parenthesis within the regular expression? `(.*?)`
I just want to get the email address: `demo@example.com`

This is what I got so far:

```
var regex = new RegExp('E-mail:\\s(.*?)<br>', 'mg');
var matches = document.body.innerHTML.match(regex);
```

And yeap, I know using `exec` on a loop can retrieve on an array just the email. But I would have to manually create the loop and get what I want:

```
var regex = new RegExp('E-mail:\\s(.*?)<br>', 'mg');
var allMatches = [];
while( matches = regex.exec(document.body.innerHTML)){
    allMatches.push(matches[1]);
}
console.log(allMatches);
```

Comment: What doesn't Work? Your code look all right to me. Please explain what doesn't Work.

Comment: Normally you would use look behind for that, but JavaScript regex doesn't support that.

Comment: @PoulBak I want to get only the email when using `match` instead of the whole string "Email: demo@example.com"

Comment: Yes, but then you need a regex engine, that supports look behind, like .Net.

Comment: When using `match` with a regex compiled with `g` modifier, all captures are discarded. Use `RegExp#exec` in a loop. It is a very well-known issue.

Comment: Thanks for the info @WiktorStribiżew